# Problems with unity appearence

Tags: unity, themes, appearance

Maybe the appearance window is completely messed up. Until yesterday i wasn't able to change the desktop background.

After trying  `unity --reset`, the desktop background was changeable but now themes are not changing.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could reinstall unity completely with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity`